# SQL - Using a Group By with Adding More Columns Showing Additional Rows

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT H1.INCIDENT_NUMBER,
    H1.HISTORY_START_DATE,
    H1.ASSIGNED_GROUP, 
    H1.STATUS
FROM INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC as H1
WHERE H1.INCIDENT_NUMBER IN (
   SELECT INCIDENT_NUMBER
   FROM INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC
   WHERE ASSIGNED_GROUP LIKE ' DS$_%' ESCAPE '$'
)
ORDER BY H1.INCIDENT_NUMBER
```

Part of the results are shown as below:

[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish from here is for each INCIDENT_NUMBER, grab the MAX(HISTORY_START_DATE). I've tried using the 'Group By' but I need to keep the ASSIGNED_GROUP AND STATUS columns and when I add them back into the 'Group By,' I'm getting multiple rows again for each INCIDENT_NUMBER.

Results I am looking for:

[image]

Do I need a subquery or something? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Row_Number()` with `Partition by` like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT H1.INCIDENT_NUMBER,
    H1.ASSIGNED_GROUP, 
    H1.HISTORY_START_DATE AS MAX_Date
    H1.STATUS,
    Row_Number() over (Partition by H1.INCIDENT_NUMBER order by H1.HISTORY_START_DATE desc) rw
FROM INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC as H1
WHERE H1.INCIDENT_NUMBER IN (
   SELECT INCIDENT_NUMBER
   FROM INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC
   WHERE ASSIGNED_GROUP LIKE ' DS$_%' ESCAPE '$'
)) t
where t.rw=1 
order by t.INCIDENT_NUMBER
```

Comment: Could you explain how the Row_Number function works? I researched it a bit but didn't quite understand it.

Comment: @Joe this is a great source to read about it: https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-the-sql-row-number-function/